# CSS Selector For Last Element With Class Within Element With Class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I'm using bootstrap and I have placed my inputs within their own `.form-group`. All my inputs are also contained within a div with a `.well` class.

I want to remove the default `margin-bottom:15px` that bootstrap has for `.form-group` but only if its the last instance of `.form-group` within its parent `.well` div.

```
<div class="well">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="m-b-none">Name</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="Name">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="m-b-none">Surname</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="Surname">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want to remove set the `margin-bottom` to 0px on the last `form-group` within each of the elements with the class `well`.

I tried the below code but it just applied the style to all .form-groups

```
.well .form-group:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

```css
.well .form-group:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="well">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="well">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You code seems to work. Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: Im grabbing an exact copy of the code and I think I can see why its not working. All inputs are wrapped in their own form-group so the selector would see that as the last of type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector I was trying actually works. The HTML is produced using some C# extension methods and I hadn't realised all the inputs were being wrapped in a `.form-group` div. The CSS selector would have seen that as the `last-of-type` for the `.well`. Once I removed this div the selector worked.

```
.well .form-group:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use bootstrap for this. `mb-0` is a bootstrap utility class to set the `margin-bottom` to 0.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="well">
   <div class="form-group">
     <input/>
   </div>
   <div class="mb-0 form-group">
     <input/>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="well">
   <div class="form-group">
     <input/>
   </div>
   <div class="mb-0 form-group">
     <input/>
   </div>
</div>
```

More on `mb-0`: [What is class=“mb-0” in Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574776/what-is-class-mb-0-in-bootstrap-4?noredirect=1)

Comment: I know I could have done this but I dont want to go through every input I've added so far and add that class. I want to just use one CSS selector to capture the whole project.

Comment: You will face a cascade of problem by doing that. Take the habit of writing functional CSS: https://rangle.io/blog/styling-with-functional-css/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add a class, You can also do this directly with the `:last-child` selector.

```
.well .form-group:last-child {
     margin-bottom: 0!important;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `>` to specify the next child of `.well` of type `div`

`.well > div.form-group:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}`